# Daily & monthly availability percentages via Prometheus? (or monthly uptime perc)

Tags: docker-swarm, prometheus

Needed are availability figures for one or more Docker services

We use Prometheus to collect metrics in a Docker Swarm environment. Works fine!

How can we get daily and/or monthly metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion in the other answer may be a good step forward. Thank you **@vinodk**.

Asking many developers on this subject, I finally found a good solution.

The solution is:

- Use Prometheus as a data source of the availability measurements. Prometheus is needed anyway for regular monitoring.
- To prevent that the monitoring data gets lost when a Docker image or node crashes, map the data volume to an external file storage, e.g. S3.
- Use a data visualisation tool that performs a SINGLE but very powerful Prometheus API call.

As an example, this Prometheus API call gives the daily up (or availability) time over a period of a number of days. Take care of using Z/GMT times.

```
http://prometheus-server/prometheus/api/v1/query_range?query=avg_over_time(up[1h])*100&start=2019-12-15T06:00:00.000Z&end=2019-12-17T16:59:59.000Z&step=1d
```

What about alternatives?

1) Store the results of Prometheus in a remote database and query it seperately. It's a bit of overkill for just retrieving the availability percentages for a month.

2) You could use the tool 'Telegraph' which has a smaller memory footprint. It can store the data in InfluxDb. I like the Prometheus solution / architecture / standard for monitoring, so this option is not the right one in my case.

3) We use Spring Boot for our applications. Spring Boot **Admin** is not applicable because it only looks to the current situation and is not persisting the results.

Answer (score 1):

[Recording Rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) will help you to aggregate and group your ingested metrics on regular basis and their results are ingested into prometheus.